# When I run this method it hits the RedirectToAction but not the breakpoint i have placed above it

Tags: debugging, model-view-controller, breakpoints

I have a class for a cart in a store and when the buy method gets run it skips the breakpoint and still hits the RedirectToAction at the bottom of the method. This is the code for the method

```
public ActionResult Buy(int productid /*string optionid*/)
        {
            Product productModel = new Product();

            List<ProductOptionJoin> productOptionJoins = GetProductOptions();

            var test = productOptionJoins.Where(x  => x.ProductID == productid && x.OptionID.ToString() == "1" /*optionid*/).Select(x  => new CartItem() {  getProduct = x.GetProduct, getOption = x.GetOption });

            var i = test;

            if (Session["cart"] == null)
            {
                List<CartItem> cart = new List<CartItem>();
                //cart.Add(new CartItem { getProduct = productModel.find(id), getOption = productModel.find(id), Quantity = 1 });
                Session["cart"] = cart;
            }
            else
            {
                List<CartItem> cart = (List<CartItem>)Session["cart"];
                int index = isExist(productid);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    cart[index].Quantity++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //cart.Add(new CartItem { getProduct = productModel.find(id), getOption = productModel.find(id), Quantity = productModel.find(id) });
                }
                Session["cart"] = cart;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating the session variable at the end, maybe put it above?

```
Product productModel = new Product();

            List<ProductOptionJoin> productOptionJoins = GetProductOptions();

            var test = productOptionJoins.Where(x  => x.ProductID == productid && x.OptionID.ToString() == "1" /*optionid*/).Select(x  => new CartItem() {  getProduct = x.GetProduct, getOption = x.GetOption });

            var i = test;

            Session["cart"] = xyz;
```